# Solutions of $z^n+\dfrac {a_{n-1}}{c}z^{n-1}+\dots \dfrac {a_1}{c^{n-1}}z+\dfrac {a_0}{c^n}=0$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

According to Introduction to Topology. Pure and Applied by C Adams & R Franzosa :

> Consider equation
>
> $z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots a_1z+a_0=0$.
>
> This equation has a solution in $\mathbb C$ if and only if for each positive real number c, the equation
>
> $z^n+\dfrac {a_{n-1}}{c}z^{n-1}+\dots \dfrac {a_1}{c^{n-1}}z+\dfrac {a_0}{c^n}=0$
>
> has a solution in $\mathbb C$.

This claim is written without mentioning a proof. I thought that it is trivial since $a_i$'s are arbitrary, if the first equation has a solution in $\mathbb C$ implies that the second equation has a solution in $\mathbb C$ and vice versa. But it has been asked in exercise to prove, so I think it may need a proof more than what I thought to be trivial. Would you please help me how to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trivial indeed: $z$ satisfies

$$z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots a_1z+a_0=0$$

if and only if $\frac zc $ satisfies

$$z^n+\dfrac {a_{n-1}}{c}z^{n-1}+\dots \dfrac {a_1}{c^{n-1}}z+\dfrac {a_0}{c^n}=0$$